# Location of App's "USB Storage app" and "SD card"?

Tags: applications

From the below screenshot, can anyone please tell the location(or rather path) of the "USB storage app" and "SD card" that an android application points to?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot</sup>

I write a text file in the `/mnt/sdcard` folder but I don't see any changes in the SD card parameter.

Comment: Sdcard is at /sdcard/ or the path you've given. So you wrote a text file with this application you've taken the screenshot with?

Comment: @Peanut I'm just copying a .txt file into sdcard by setting the directory as Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). I want the text file size shown in the "SD card" field.

Comment: Odd, I would have thought that would change it. I think although your questions "What are the paths" isn't developer orientated your actual query of "Why isn't the value reported changing" is a dev question and should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Peanut I had posted there initially but was lead to post here instead.

Comment: 1) it would have helped to name the device. I guess 2) it either has an internal and an external SDCard, or/and the "SD card" entry there does not refer to `/sdcard` but to another place (e.g. `/sdcard/external_sd`). 3) this rather looks like a development question, as Peanut pointed out: end-users don't access things like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Oh, besides: If my above guess about an internal SDcard was correct, despite the functions name, that's what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot is information regarding a specific app on an Android device and how much space that app uses. Saving a text file in `/mnt/sdcard` will not have an effect on the numbers you see here. Depending on your phone and what version you have, you can usually go to `Settings > Storage` to see you memory usage.

Comment: See his comment, he's written the application himself and written the .txt file using that.

Comment: This was moved from `Super User`. Check out [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410280/where-does-my-app-data-save-on-android) for a simular issue.